# How do I lower the log severity without changing code?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, log4j2

#### Short version:

**How do I, preferably in log4j2 configuration, record a log message that the Java code uses [`Logger.error`](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#error(java.lang.String)), to be recorded as a [`Logger.info`](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info(java.lang.String))?**

Ideally, I'd like to do this in my xml configuration. I can imagine a way to do this with private static field reflection and a custom `Logger` implementation, but that seems very hacky and is a last resort.

#### Longer version:

<sub>Full scenario for [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200235) reasons.</sub>

I have third party libraries that are using SLF4J, and I also have a tool that scans my logs and notifies me if there are errors.

Currently, the third party library records things as errors that, while technically ARE errors, are transient and already have retry logic. As such, these logs can be a bit noisy sometimes. I also, with a different tool (which doesn't use my logs in any way), have the ability to record that these transient errors are occurring so I can see if there are spikes in these transient errors that could be indicative of a real problem. If this edge case happens, I'd **like the error messages to be *present* in my logs** so I can debug the issue.

In order to reduce the noise of my log scanner tool most of the time, but preserve the messages if I need them, I'd like to have the library's calls to `Logger.error` get recorded as `Logger.info`. How can I do this?

Comment: So you want them to be logged, just on a different level? Not turn off the logging for those packages?

Comment: What? Why? The error should have a single error level and its your configuration / filtering that should change. It should be error and you should switch between collecting error or info. Why would the level of the error change?

You could put in some variable that gets assigned from a config and put your logging call inside a method that checks the variable and logs at one level or the other. But I'd make sure you really want that.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, that's correct. I can turn logging off for those packages, but that's less than ideal for the edge case scenario. It is currently my plan B, though.

Comment: @SpacePrez I can't do that because the logging is called from inside the 3p library.

Comment: All the more reason you shouldn't be doing it in the first place. You know you can configure error level per-package, right? Just set it to ERROR for most things and set it to OFF for specifically the class throwing that error.

Comment: @SpacePrez I already know I can do that, as I said to Kayaman that is plan B.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to redirect the logs for that package to a dfiferent log file/sink, if the main issue here is the log being too chatty. If you need to debug, you can then combine the log files.

Comment: @Kayaman That might be the easiest way to go, it is harder than you are making it sound (because of a bunch of other configurations that are tightly coupled with the log file names e.g. my log scanner), but it might still be easiest.

Comment: It's not a very good idea to have logic dependent on log file names. You could even ditch files completely and switch to a database. Plenty of choices.